# Kubernetes service makes outbound connections - how to make it originate from a virtual ip

Tags: networking, kubernetes, ip

I currently have a Kubernetes cluster, and we have a service that needs to be accessible from a virtual ip.

This in itself is not a difficult process - can use keepalived and nodeports. However, I need that service when its making outbound connections to be bound to that virtual ip (this is due to a legacy system we interact with).

Is there anything in place or that I can use that will help me with this in a generic way.

I essentially want traffic from a specific service to come out of the virtual ip and not the kubernetes host's ip.

Comment: When you say virtual IP, you mean pod IP?

Comment: You will probably have to setup the node(s) running keepalived to be also a proxy server running squid or some other proxy software and configure your pod  to use that proxy server.  I haven't heard of any cloud native outbound proxy yet.

Comment: Actually  there is a solution, I haven't tried yet: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/transparent-proxy-and-filtering-on-k8s-with-initializers

Comment: @suren

No, I mean an actual virtual ip (as in an ip address that floats from node to node using arps)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hostNetwork: true` for your deployment, this will start your pods outside of NAT, and you will be able to see all the system interfaces.

Keep in mind that nodePort won’t be available when hostNetwork is enabled.